# How to implement Singleton for Xamarin forms using PRISM?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, singleton, prism, viewmodellocator

I am working on Xamarin.Forms using PRISM library for MVVM architecture.

So, the problem is whenever I navigating between pages using INavigationService always the class/ViewModel is instantiating newly, so already assigned strings are becoming empty/null. I am registering page and ViewModel in App.Xaml.cs as below:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginViewModel>();
}
```

How to handle not to instantiate newly always or need to Instantiate only one time throughout the app working.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not supported for a variety of reasons. Suffice it to say a Singleton ViewModel is a very bad practice and causes a lot of problems. While we cannot stop you from registering the ViewModel as a singleton with the container this WILL introduce bugs into your app.

### Appropriate Ways

You haven't really provided any details of what it is you're trying to instantiate but one of these methods should work for you.

Use IInitialize or INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo

```cs
public class LoginViewModel : IInitialize
{
    public void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        // Initialize anything you need to for the life cycle of your ViewModel here
    }
}
```

Use a Singleton Service

```cs
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>();
    }
}

public class LoginViewModel
{
    private ISomeService _someService { get; }

    public LoginViewModel(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
        UserName = _someService.UserName;
    }

    // simplified for example
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    private void DoLogin()
    {
        _someService.UserName = UserName;

    }
}
```

I should also point out that if you are looking for something to last from one session to the next of your app running then you could use the built in `IApplicationStore` which exposes the Properties Dictionary and SavePropertiesAsync from the Application in an interface that keeps your code testable.

Comment: very helpful if you could help to me in this. In the Xamarin.Forms project, to implement MVVM design pattern I have been using PRISM library. To register Views with respective ViewModels I am registering them by overriding RegisterTypes method in App.xaml.cs.
When I am trying to navigate between Views by using INavigation service in the every ViewModel constructor, every time the ViewModel is getting Initialised. It results the already assigned View properties in the ViewModel are getting empty/ null. 
To overcome this I am trying to implement Singleton in which I need support.

Comment: I landed here because my ViewModel was being instantiated twice for some reason. It might help somebody that this was because I was asking for it explicitly in my View's constructor, so that Prism was creating it once for that, and a second time due to auto-wiring. The solution is to disable the latter: `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="False"`

Comment: Prism 8 does address this issue as some changes were made to ensure everywhere that Prism might set the AutowireViewModel="True" now calls a single method which checks to ensure the BindingContext is null